# Reclipping Toyota Fender clips

Tags: body-work, bumper

My Corolla bumper has been partially detached after being lifted by a kerb. I have reattached it fairly well (only the right side was damaged) but there are some clips which won't reattach.

I'm wondering whether they are simply broken, or if there's a trick to getting them to reattach.

If they are broken, would putting a couple of small self tapping screws through the black and into the white be a good idea?

[image: the clip in question]
[image: a view of the clip from behind]

Comment: Caution; refrain from plain or galvanized self tapping screws. They will eventually rust from exposure to road salts, rain, etc. Plastic ages from normal weathering with uv resistant treatment to forestall drying out. They eventually dry out and crack, especially in very hot and freezing temps. If the snap on tabs are worn, missing, either try stainless sheet metal screws or drilling a hole to use the plastic reusable rivets used on many vehicles, allowing disassembly and reassemby using the rivets repeatedly.